# Calculate discount

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This is my first question here, thus please have mercy. :)

I have minimum and maximum number of products and minimum and maximum price, and I want to calculate the discount depending of number of bought products.

```
minProducts = 1
maxProducts = 4000
minPrice = 0.8
maxPrice = 3.2
```

- If they buy 4000 products then is the price 0.8 per product
- if they buy 800 products then is the price 1.6 per product
- and if they buy only one product then is the price 3.2.

How can I calculate the price per product if they buy for example 860 or 520 products?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If they buy $800-3999$ products, then they pay half price ($\frac{3.2}{1.6} = \frac12$), so 50%.

If they buy $4000+$ products, they pay quarter price, so 25%.

EDIT: I may be reading this wrong. Is the discount different for say 800 and 850 products?

In that case, I (and WolframAlpha) is unable to find a function that fits these criteria. See examples:

[Linear fit](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=linear%20fit%20%7B1,1%7D,%7B800,%200.5%7D,%7B4000,0.25%7D) fails, as the points are not colinear.

Similarly, I attempted with [quadratic fit](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=quadratic%20fit%20%7B1,1%7D,%7B800,%200.5%7D,%7B4000,0.25%7D), [cubic fit](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cubic%20fit%20%7B1,1%7D,%7B800,%200.5%7D,%7B4000,0.25%7D), [exponential fit](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=exp%20fit%20%7B1,1%7D,%7B800,%200.5%7D,%7B4000,0.25%7D), and [logarithmic fit](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log%20fit%20%7B1,1%7D,%7B800,%200.5%7D,%7B4000,0.25%7D).

Note that the polynomial fits (quadratic and cubic) are able to hit the points perfectly, but they result in some weird discounts somewhere in between.

Comment: Yes, it's actually different for every product. For example 800 = 1,6 and 801 = 1,6001 ...

Comment: @Boky - Ah, gotcha. See edited answer. It seems difficult to find functions that conserve the values you propose while keeping sane discounts in between.